# Past participle of stand

Tags: relative-clauses, past-participles, participles

I'm new to this community, I hope the question fits this somewhat.

Say we have a sentence:

> The tree which stands in the garden is beautiful.

Now using participle construction this becomes:

> The tree standing in the garden is beautiful.

However in the past tense the original statement becomes:

> The tree which stood in the garden was beautiful.

The past participle of *stand* is *stood* - does that mean the sentence becomes:

> The tree stood in the garden was beautiful.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up various things here. The past tense of “The tree which stands in the garden” is “The tree which stood in the garden”. _Was standing_ is the past tense of the progressive construction _is standing_, which you don’t mention anywhere. _Standing_ on its own is a participle, not a tensed form, and you can’t just substitute a different participle to make it past tense – since it’s a subordinate, non-tensed clause, its tense follows the main tense, so you can keep _standing_ and just change _is beautiful_ to _was beautiful_.

Comment: Ah, right that was where I've gone wrong. 
However the question still remains, what would be - if one exists - the participle construction of:
> "The tree which stood in the garden was beautiful"
Also thanks for the improved formatting in my post!

Comment: The past participle is also used in the present perfect, which will probably sound normal/ordinary to you: *Notre Dame has stood there for almost eight centuries". So the past participle of *stand* is *stood*.

Comment: @Folling You have got the past participle correct but the phrase loses it's emphasis on the subject. That's why we use 'which' there.

Comment: If I may ask: How exactly does the sentence lose its emphasis on the subject? Afterall it's still about the tree having stood in the garden at some point and having been beautiful when that was the case, I believe